# Is there a way to load language resources per user with html5?

Tags: html, manifest, offline, multilingual

I'm trying to build an html5 website that's multilingual and allows the user to work offline. How can I download specific language resource per user (when they select their language) without having to download all language files (i.e the manifest file is for all connections)?

Comment: is that manifest thing a special framework? Is this multi-language tool home-made?

Comment: No, the manifest is used with the cache manifest in html5. This allows you to select files that can be cached and accessed offline. I need to be able to cache a resource file per user depending on their selected language.

Comment: Can you not have separate manifest files for each language (say lang_en.xyz, lang_fr.xyz, etc.) and whenever a user selects a language, save the corresponding file with a generic name (lang.xyz) that can be replaced if the user changes his preference

Comment: No, there's only one manifest file for each web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about generating one manifest per language, and then echoing from php the correct  tag? Pretty ugly, but should do the trick don't you think?

Edit: of course it means anyway that there is a default manifest, with a default language pack...